# Encoding Polish Ogonek a̜ vs ą

Tags: unicode, encoding, fonts

I have noticed, that Liberation Sans (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Liberation-Sans)  will always show the letter like this: **ą**, regardless whether it is built using Unicode:

*U+0061+U+031C* or *U+0105*

Whereas other fonts seem to have two different representations: **a̜ ą**

See also:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/105/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/031c/index.htm

Besides the different Unicodes is there any **semantic** difference?

Comment: If you paste "a̜ ą" into the Font Squirrel test drive, there's a clear difference. The positioning of the half-ring might indicate a bug in the font, though.

Comment: FWIW, the decomposed form of `U+0105` is `U+0061,U+0328`, so `U+0061,U+031C` is *not* canonically equivalent.

Comment: I agree, I just tested the string "Lektura dla pocza̜tkuja̜cych" with both, Liberation-Sans and Junicode and there is a noticable difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+031C is Combining Left Half Ring Below.

But there is also U+0328 Combining Ogonek.

Are you sure you have the correct combining character? The "wrong" one is likely to lead to less than optimal glyphs being selected from the typeface.

Comment: So the actual content is this, which I receive from an external data source: "Lektura dla pocza̜tkuja̜cych" which when tested in Font Squirrel test drive (https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/liberation-sans) shows clearly the ogonek kind of misplaced

Comment: Still don't know which representation is the correct one, or if both have a valid meaning in polish?

Comment: @SebastianRiemer I found U+0328 from the Wikipedia page *[Ogonek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogonek#Encoding)*, but checking the Unicode Code Charts and/or Standard would be the definitive source. That an external part gets the encoding "wrong" could be either their mistake or historical: when they started the "correct" character was not available.

Comment: @SebastianRiemer Additionally, performing a string replacement on the input should be possible (but depends on the platform/language you are using).

Comment: Thanks for all of your feedback!
I'll accept the single answer as I think the issue has been addressed sufficiently!